# Why is this concatenation of the float values in pandas dataframe is giving NaN output?

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, concatenation

I have bunch of pandas dataframe with float values. I want to concatenate them using pandas.

```
df1 = 

                                 hapX_Sp_Sum
  contig pos      F1_2ms04h_PI             
0  2      16229767 726                   3.5
1  2      16229783 726                   3.5
2  2      16229880 726                   2.0
3  2      16229891 726                   2.0
4  2      16229982 726                   0.0
5  2      16229992 726                   0.0

df2 =

                                     hapX_My_Sum
  contig pos      F1_2ms04h_PI             
0  2      16229767 726                   0.0
1  2      16229783 726                   0.0
2  2      16229880 726                   0.0
3  2      16229891 726                   0.0
4  2      16229982 726                   0.0
5  2      16229992 726                   0.0
```

I concatenate them as:

```
frames = [df1, df2]
merged_df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)
```

The output I am getting:

```
                                     hapX_My_Sum  hapX_Sp_Sum
  contig pos      F1_2ms04h_PI                          
0  2      16229767 726                   0.0          NaN
1  2      16229783 726                   0.0          NaN
2  2      16229880 726                   0.0          NaN
3  2      16229891 726                   0.0          NaN
4  2      16229982 726                   0.0          NaN
5  2      16229992 726                   0.0          NaN
```

The values in each column is a float, but why am I running into this NaN problem? I generated these dataframe using `pd.sum()` of the float values, which should result in each value in the column being float. This is weird, any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks normal to me as you are concatenating along the rows. So yes, `hapX_Sp_Sum` is of course empty in the first dataframe. If you print more lines you'll find non empty values (but NaNs for the other columns this time)

I suspect what you really want to do is

`merged_df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 0)`

Comment: I think I was doing `axis = 0`, using `axis = 1` works now. thanks,